# How to use feed_dict in slim.learning.train of tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I read an example in tf-slim-mnist, and read one or two answers in Google, but all of them feed data to an 'images' tensor and a 'labels' tensor from an already filled-up tenser of data.  For example, in tf-slim-mnist,

```
# load batch of dataset
images, labels = load_batch(
    dataset,
    FLAGS.batch_size,
    is_training=True)

def load_batch(dataset, batch_size=32, height=28, width=28, is_training=False):
    data_provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(dataset)

    image, label = data_provider.get(['image', 'label'])

    image = lenet_preprocessing.preprocess_image(
        image,
        height,
        width,
        is_training)

    images, labels = tf.train.batch(
        [image, label],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

    return images, labels
```

Another example, in tensorflow github issues #5987,

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    image, label = input('train', FLAGS.dataset_dir)
    images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size, capacity=1000 + 3 * FLAGS.batch_size, min_after_dequeue=1000)
    images_validation, labels_validation = inputs('validation', FLAGS.dataset_dir, 5000)
    images_test, labels_test = inputs('test', FLAGS.dataset_dir, 10000)
```

Because my data is of variable size, it is hard to fill up a tensor of data beforehand.

Is there any way to use feed_dict with slim.learning.train()?  Is it a proper way to add feed_dict as an argument to the train_step_fn()?  If yes, how?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think feed_dict is not a good way when input data size varies and hard to fill in memory.

Convert your data into tfrecords is a more proper way. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/datasets/download_and_convert_mnist.py) is the example of convert data. You can deal with the data by [TFRecordReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TFRecordReader) and [parse_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example) to deal with output file.